# How can I change my cursor behavior?

Tags: xubuntu, cursor

When I am typing, my mouse cursor, if left on the text, will eventually auto-click in whatever space in the the text box I happen to be, causing me to type in the middle of a sentence. Also, the cursor in the text box will frequently stop mid-word and the screen will scroll down all of a sudden when pressing the space bar while typing. My question is, how do I change this behavior because it is driving me absolutely bat crap crazy. I have an Acer Aspire One D257 Netbook. I am not sure if it's a Xubuntu problem because it does this while I am using Windows 7 too. Any help would be nice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your hands get too close to the touchpad when you type, accidentally triggering mouse clicks. In the settings for the mouse and touchpad, there's a setting for deactivating the touchpad while typing; make sure that one is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to try the program called GPointingDeviceSettings. It allows you to deactivate clicking by tapping the touchpad. It's in the repositories, so you can just follow http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gpointing-device-settings to install it.